# Traduction de « Unternehmenswert / Shareholder value »

Tags: traduction, allemand, finance

Je suis chargé de traduire un document sur la sécurité de l'information de l'allemand au français, quand je suis tombé sur le mot *Unternehmenswert*. J'ai vite trouvé qu'en anglais une des possibilité serait *Shareholder value*, puis j'ai trouvé un [lien traduisant ce mot par *fonds de commerce*](http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=56155&idForum=13&lp=frde&lang=de). Le site, `dict.leo.org`, est assez réputé pour un service de bonne qualité, mais cette information venant du forum et datant de 2006, je ne sais pas si je peux lui faire confiance.

Est-ce que quelqu'un pourrait m'aider à confirmer cette traduction, ou bien me proposer une traduction plus appropriée ?

**EDIT:** Dans le document que je traduis, le mot a été associé par l'auteur au mot anglais *assets*.

**EDIT 2:** À part la traduction proposée par `dict.leo.org`, *fonds de commerce*, je peux faire une traduction des parties qui compose le mot. *Unternehmen*, c'est une entreprise. *Wert* est traduit par valeur. Et le mot anglais *shareholder* signifie un actionnaire, tandis que des *assets* sont des actifs financiers. Mais j'ai l'impression que c'est un cas où ce genre de traduction grossière peut nous mener sur la mauvaise piste, si l'on ne fait pas attention.

**EDIT 3:** Pendant que je continuais mon travail de traduction, je suis tombé sur une piste, qui après quelques recherches, m'a mené à un lien entre mon document et [la norme ISO/CEI 27001](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/CEI_27001). La page wikipedia mentionne le terme *"biens sensibles d'une entreprise"*. Je suis conscient que la personne la plus apte à me répondre, comme il a été mentionné plusieurs fois, serait quelqu’un s'y connaissant en économie, mais je me demande: Ne serait-ce pas le terme que je cherche?

Comment: En réaction à EDIT 3 : je ne vois pas l'aspect sensible dans Unternehmenswert, mais *biens* pourrait refléter le sens. Dans le domaine de la sécurité, c'est comme cela qu'on traduit l'anglais *asset*, qui signifie les choses que l'on cherche à protéger ; je ne connais pas le terme allemand. Il faudrait un peu plus de contexte.

Comment: @Gilles: Je peux donner quelques exemples de ce qui est assemblé sous le nom *Unternehmenswert*: *Infrastruktur* (*Standort*, *Raum*, *Inventar*, *Schnittstellen*, etc.), *Aufbau-Organisation* (*Abteilung*, *Mitarbeiter*, etc.), *Ablauf-Organisation* (*Dienst*, *Information*, *Assetsgruppen*, etc.). Lentement je pense que la bon terme est bien *valeur de l'entreprise*. Comme quoi la traduction littéraire (dans un contexte spécifique) est parfois la bonne.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il s'agit manifestement d'un terme technique d'économie ou plus probablement de droit des affaires. Il vaudrait mieux consulter un dictionnaire spécialisé voire confirmation à un spécialiste (ce que je ne suis absolument pas). Il est dommage que [l'article de Wikipédia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unternehmenswert) ne donne pas de traduction (sauf en polonais et en ukrainien).

La base [IATE](http://iate.europa.eu/iatediff/SearchByQueryLoad.do), élaborée à partir de documents multilingues en rapport avec l'Union Européenne, donne les associations suivantes :

- (accounting, law) [de] *Gesamtwert*, *Unternehmenswert*; [en] *going concern value*; [fr] *valeur de cession globale*
- (law) [en] *going concern value*; [fr] *valeur d'utilité*, *valeur d'exploitation*
- (business organization) [en] *going concern value*; [fr] *valeur de cession globale*

Je comprends cela comme une manière d'évaluer la valeur d'une entreprise qui tient compte de son activité courante. Je crains que *shareholder value* soit un contresens, une autre manière de valuer l'entreprise.

En fouillant un peu, [ce site d'investissement](http://www.value-investing.eu/de/Strategies/Negative_Enterprise_Value_Stock_Screener) appelle « negativer Unternehmenswert » des entreprises qui valent moins que leur réserve de capital. Je ne trouve rien de plus probant sur les sites de l'UE.

En Suisse, le [finance wiki de l'Université de Zürich](http://www.bf.uzh.ch/financewiki/index.php/Unternehmenswert) donne une [explication du terme](http://www.bf.uzh.ch/financewiki/index.php/Unternehmenswert), avec la traduction anglaise *company value* qui me paraît bien vague. Il existe même un site [unternehmenswert.ch](http://www.unternehmenswert.ch/), malheureusement purement germanophone ce qui n'aide pas à trouver le bon terme en français.

Answer (score 2):

L'article de [Wikipedia de](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unternehmenswert) est en propostion de fusion avec [Entreprise value](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_Value)

> Unternehmenswert oder Enterprise Value (auch Entity Value, Firm Value oder Aggregate Value) bezeichnet im Rahmen einer Unternehmensbewertung den geschätzten, bzw. errechneten Wert eines Unternehmens unabhängig von seiner Finanzierung.

Lequel est en interwiki avec [Valeur de l'entreprise](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valeur_de_l%27entreprise)

> Dans son sens technique utilisé par les analystes financiers, la valeur d'une entreprise (enterprise value, abrégé en EV) désigne la valeur de marché des capitaux investis dans cette entreprise.

De plus le calcul semble correspondre : comparer

> *Unternehmenswert = Eigenkapital + Nettofinanzverbindlichkeiten*
>   […]
>   *Der Unternehmenswert ist hier die Summe aus Marktkapitalisierung plus Nettofinanzverbindlichkeiten (Schulden minus vorhandene liquide Mittel).*

avec

> Valeur de l'entreprise = capitalisation boursière + dette financière nette + intérêts minoritaires.

Sous réserve de confirmation par des économistes ou de meilleurs germanophones que moi, je dirais donc que la bonne traduction est *valeur de l'entreprise*. Tout simplement.

Comment: Je confirme cette réponse. Il s'agit de la valeur d'entreprise, qu'on note EV en économie (pour l'anglais Enterprise Value). Pour mesurer la valeur "réelle" d'une entreprise, on utilise soit le rapport EV/EBITDA (grosso modo EV/CA de la société) ou alors le P/E ratio qui est la mise en regard de la valeur boursière avec le bénéfice annuel (=rendement maximum en terme de dividendes).

Answer (score 0):

> Unternehmenswert: Der Wert eines Unternehmens entspricht dem Nutzen

La valeur que l'entreprise accorde à l'[utilité](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utilit%C3%A9) (L'utilité étant une mesure de la satisfaction).

Il apparait donc que "fonds de commerce" n'est pas adapté. Le fond de commerce étant une valeur intrinsèque d'un commerce à attirer le client (nom, marque, clientèle existante, ...). La notion d'utilité est un concept économique, utilisé notamment par les néo-classiques. Elle semble liée à la notion de prise de risque, mais mes compétences en économie restent limitées.

Comment: Je pense que tu fais un contresens: ce n'est pas une valeur accordée par l'entreprise mais une valeur de l'entreprise. Et l'utilité n'est probablement pas à prendre dans le sens de satisfaction ici.

Comment: @Gilles possible, mon allemand n'est plus ce qu'il était :P